# What's the meaning of "make it rain X"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What's the meaning of "make it rain X"? Looking up the idiom I found the following definitions:

> (idiomatic) to bring prosperity or work to an enterprise by selling,
>   inventing or other productive or successful activity
>
> (idiomatic) to throw a substantial amount of paper money so that it
>   falls on a crowd, audience, performer, or group of performers, often
>   as a way to show off one's wealth
>
> Used other than with a figurative or idiomatic meaning: see make,‎
>   it,‎ rain.

Seeing the third definition makes me think "make it rain X" means make it rain anything literally, is it the case? Then if it is so, can we say "make it rain blood"? Does that literally mean "make it rain physical blood"? I am asking, because it sounds odd to me.

Comment: You can't leave *X* out of the question. Also, don't think I've ever heard *make it rain [something]* before. I've heard *it is raining [something]* before. For instance, *it's raining cats and dogs*. But what follows *raining* changes the meaning of the expression. So, I'm actually questioning where the quoted definition comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means "cause blood to fall from the sky like rain".  Is that odd? Yes! Unless you are a god you can't do this.